# Множество непереведенных строк

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

1. В профиле любого участника (при просмотре им самим) есть строка, отвечающая за посещаемость:

   > visited x days, x consecutive

   > [image: Снимок 1]

---

2. На странице [тура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) есть не переведенный пример сообщения.

   > [image: Снимок 2]

Comment: Глупая затея с учётом текущих событий. Переводы слетают и восстанавливаются. Причина кроется где-то в подключении Channels, вероятно. Ответов от разработчиков четких нет, и пока их не будет, постить такие баги, как и пытаться исправлять их - усилия, потраченные в пустоту.

Comment: @alexolut, однако предыдущий мой вопрос так и не исправили =)

Comment: о предстоящих событиях? Так корень проблемы тот же. Его просто нельзя исправить в ситуации, когда строк не видно в системе для перевода.

Comment: @alexolut, думаю, первый комментарий стоит вынести в отдельный вопрос и пришпилить его меткой [meta-tag:важное].

Answer (score 1):

С посещением сейчас всё нормально:

> [image: на сайте давно]

В Туре вопрос уже другой и на русском:

> [image: тур]